# Tidyverse Question: Why is this tibble column, created by tribble, not recognized?

Tags: r, ggplot2, filter, tidyverse, tibble

I'm working on setting up a blood pressure monitoring system, with the immediate goal of plotting readings over time in a way that shows the category in which each reading falls. To accomplish this, the different categories will be color coded, as [here](https://www.heart.org/en/health-topics/high-blood-pressure/understanding-blood-pressure-readings).

A second goal is to migrate my knowledge and workflows to the tidyverse. Hence, I'm a novice at working with the tidyverse.

Typically there are two kinds of blood pressure, Systolic and Diastolic, both of which may be categorized by the range in which they fall (e.g., "Normal," "Elevated," etc.). My current workflow is: (1) to create a tibble containing the ranges for the two kinds, (2) use this information to construct appropriately colored ggplot rectangles for each category, (3) combine the rectangles into templates for Systolic & Diastolic blood pressure, (4) do something similar for a third template (Resting Heart Rate), (5) add to each the appropriate time series as point geometries, and (6) display this in a column of three graphs. I'm having trouble with the first two steps as shown below.

> ```
> library(tibble)
> library(tsibble)
> library(ggplot2)
>
> # Start with the background colors for blood pressure levels
> bp_colors <- 
>     c(Low = "lightblue",
>       Normal = "#39ba25",
>       Elevated = "#e3e029",
>       `Stage 1` = "#eff8c00",
>       `Stage 2` = "darkred",
>        Crisis = "red")
> # Now enter the ranges for the different kinds of reading
> bp_ranges <- tribble(
> ~TYPE,     ~LABEL,      ~CATEGORY,   ~LOW,   ~HIGH,  
> #-----|-------------|-------------|-------|--------
> "SBP",  "Systolic",        "Low",      0,      90,
> "SBP",  "Systolic",     "Normal",     90,     120,
> "SBP",  "Systolic",   "Elevated",    120,     129,  
> "SBP",  "Systolic",    "Stage 1",    130,     139,
> "SBP",  "Systolic",    "Stage 2",    140,     179,
> "SBP",  "Systolic",     "Crisis",    180,     400,
> # See https://www.scienceabc.com/eyeopeners/how-high-can-a-blood-pressure-go.html
> "DBP",  "Diastolic",       "Low",      0,      60,
> "DBP",  "Diastolic",    "Normal",     60,      80,
> "DBP",  "Diastolic",  "Elevated",     80,      80,
> "DBP", "Diastolic",    "Stage 1",     80,      89,
> "DBP", "Diastolic",    "Stage 2",     90,     119,  
> "DBP", "Diastolic",     "Crisis",    120,     400,
> # See https://www.scienceabc.com/eyeopeners/how-high-can-a-blood-pressure-go.html
> )
>
> # Now create the SBP & DBP templates.
>
> SBP_ranges <- filter(bp_ranges, TYPE == "SBP")
> ```

And this is as far as I get. The last statement throws this error:

> ```
> Error in filter(bp_ranges, TYPE == "SBP") : object 'TYPE' not found
> ```

What's wrong?

Comment: You haven't loaded `dplyr` so the function you're calling is `stats::filter()` not `dplyr::filter()`.

Comment: By George this does it! Thanks!